# OpenIddict with two-factor authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

Well the title pretty much explains it all, but here is what I am trying to do:

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 1.0 application that needs to support authentication with JWT. This is very easily done with OpenIddict, but OpenIddict is one of those "magically works in the background" frameworks.

I would like to keep the simplicity of OpenIddict, but change it's default behaviour by using Identity and it's two-factor authentication features instead of just a username/password login.

I haven't found a way to provide a custom login manager to OpenIddict. Is there anyone who has experience with this?

Answer (score 4):

> This is very easily done with OpenIddict, but OpenIddict is one of those "magically works in the background" frameworks.

Yep it is, because it was designed to be used by people who have no idea how OAuth2 or OpenID Connect work, which is why most the protocol details are deliberately hidden (and thus, why the classes that handle the OIDC requests/responses are intentionally non-replaceable).

---

> I would like to keep the simplicity of OpenIddict, but change it's default behaviour by using Identity and it's two-factor authentication features instead of just a username/password login.

If you find it easy, I assume you're using the "resource owner password credentials grant" demonstrated in a bunch of blog posts (e.g http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/ or http://kerryritter.com/authorizing-your-net-core-mvc6-api-requests-with-openiddict-and-identity/)

Unfortunately, this (simple) OAuth2 grant is not compatible with 2-factor authentication.

---

Instead, I'd recommend switching to an interactive flow like implicit or authorization code, that will allow you to support this scenario (since you're responsible of the login part in this case).

For more information, you can take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.Server). It simply relies on the `AccountController` that comes with the default VS templates for the login step and includes a special `AuthorizationController` that handles the authorization part.

2-FA is natively supported by `AccountController`, so you shouldn't have anything to implement to enable that in your application.

Comment: Oh yea, that is a pretty good sample to get me started, thank you. I am having a hard time figuring this out for ASP.NET Core. Usually there are a million blog posts and examples that do exactly what you want, but since .NET Core is still in it's starting phase this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks @Pinpoint, the past you helped me out again with this one.