# Openiddict with 2FA/MFA using Code Flow with username and password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, openiddict

Been using openiddict for years, using the password flow, where a user just passes a username and password, which works perfectly!  But it seems that we now need to support 2Fa/MFA on a user by user basis.  We want them to still type in a username and password, but after that "maybe" type in a code for 2FA.

I have done some googling, and I believe it is recommended to use Code Flow to implement 2FA functionality, but I am confused, do I have to move all my existing "username and password" functions which currently sit in the `Exchange` method to the `Authorize` method?  I found this answer to suggest Code flow https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244159/2736022 but none of the example links seem to work now.

I am also not using the built in aspnet templates, I am using an Angular SPA to do this, currently with bearer tokens, although I would like to have the option to use Cookies or Bearer token (we have an offline app that needs Bearer token functionality).

Does anyone have a similar example to my needs that they could share, or point me in the direction needed?

When looking at the `Authorize` method, i can see that you can include extra parameters in the request and check for them using `request.HasParameter(Parameters.Username)` or `request.HasParameter(Parameters.Password)` but is the correct way to call the method?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Any auth provider such as Azure AD.

Comment: They "can" use an external identity provider instead if they choose.  If they did, that identity provider would provide the 2FA, not us

Comment: You custom login logic for OpenIddict would check the user name and password before it redirects and only complete the auth if those are correct.  You would have a property on the AppUser or whatever object you use that indicates if 2fa is required.  If you see this then you would do the logic to send the code and return back to the ui with the entry form for the code.  Don't have any examples but that is how I imagine it would work.

Comment: @AliK But is this done in the Authorize method and not the Exchange method then?  So all my username/password logic would move the Authorize method?  Yes i agree i would have a "Enabled2FA" property on the account.

Comment: It would be done wherever the authorization happens.  The code that verifies your user against the db and returns the view.  We are using MVC so we have a custom signin method that deals with the login process and returns either a view or the redirect url.  When the Authorization url is called it returns our custom login page at which point our authorization logic takes over.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute

Answer (score 0):

> I have done some googling, and I believe it is recommended to use Code Flow to implement 2FA functionality, but I am confused, do I have to move all my existing "username and password" functions which currently sit in the `Exchange` method to the `Authorize` method?

No: the authorization endpoint (typically materialized in your code as an `Authorize` MVC action) is a user-interactive endpoint, not an API endpoint: it's where you'll handle things like user login and consent forms. Once you're sure you want to return a positive authorization response with an authorization code, you call `return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` to let OpenIddict create the response for you.

If you want to keep using the resource owner password credentials grant, you still need to implement an `Exchange` action, that you'll need to tweak to also support the code flow (typically, by flowing the identity resolved from the authorization code returned during the authorization request).

To determine whether the token request received by the `Exchange` endpoint is a client credentials or authorization code grant type, you can use the `request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType()` and `request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType()` extension.

See https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Velusia/Velusia.Server for a code flow example.